# How HTML "span" tag becomes a button

Tags: javascript, html

Am helping a website modify its comment mechanism to filter comments with spam URLs.
Website is hosted by Squarespace.com which refuses any technical assistance.
Squarespace provides both HTML, to embed on your webpage, and a half million character JavaScript library file that the embedded HTML invokes.

Below is the embedded HTML code, that I have modified with a new "Post" button and a JavaScript section that checks the comment TextArea for forbidden words or phrases, in the final implementation being a list of spam URLs.
The button and the JavaScript work fine, identifying problem comments, but I do not understand how the `span` tag for `comment-btn` in the Squarespace embedded HTML invokes the JavaScript library file to actually post the comment.

If I understood how that works, I would invoke the JavaScript library file in my `if` statement.
Can anyone explain that?
Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div class="new-comment-area top-level-comment-area edit-mode">
  <div class="input">
    <form action="https://www.manhattancontrarian.com/blog/2023-2-4-in-new-york-a-very-slow-political-awakening#" method="post" class="comment-form">
      <textarea class="comment-input" id="comment" name="comment" data-defaulttext="Leave a comment here." data-edited="false" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="comment-btn-wrapper">
    <span class="btn-text preview-comment top-level-preview-btn">Preview</span>
    <span class="comment-btn sqs-system-button sqs-editable-button-font sqs-editable-button-shape sqs-button-element--primary">Post Comment...</span>    
  </div>
  <button onclick="CheckComment()">Post</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var verbotenList = ["forbidden1", "forbidden2"];
function CheckComment() {
  var commentText = document.getElementById("comment").value;
  alert(commentText);
  var verbotenFound = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < verbotenList.length; i++) {
    if (commentText.search(verbotenList[i]) >= 0) {
      verbotenFound++;
    }
  }
  alert("verbotenFound=" + verbotenFound);
  if (verbotenFound == 0) {
    alert("comment approved");
  } else {
    alert("comment not approved");
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Modified web host embedded HTML code to filter comments, do not understand how to invoke web host JavaScript library file to post approved comments.

Comment: Any element can be programmed (with JavaScript) to respond to a variety of events the browser raises upon user interaction: mouse in/out events, click events, and so on. A `<span>` tag can easily be made to look and act like a `<button>` tag. There's no good reason to do that because there is such a thing as `<button>`, but it's definitely possible.

Comment: You cane use onclick="{function_name}" or onchange="{functionname}", then define function in javascript

Comment: In the html tag add onclick="function()"

Comment: Thank you for the above suggestions, and perhaps inserting "onclick" into the comment-btn "span" would cause the "span" to invoke the onclick function, but what I need to do is prevent the comment-btn "span" from posting the comment if the onclick function rejects the comment. I presume the comment-btn "span" is invoking some JavaScript somewhere to post the comment, and I want that invoke to be under control of my filter function. I should note that "comment-btn" does appear in the Squarespace JavaScript library.